# GMail "couldn't sync", though I can watch long videos in YouTube

Tags: internal-storage, gmail, youtube

I have run out of space in my smartphone (got the message `Storage space running out: Some system functions may not work`). I know this is defined as a threshold of 10% of internal disk space (8 GB). So, I have ~ 800 MB of free space. I can watch YouTube videos in YouTube app (I'm watching [Persepolis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wb-Vle1oDB0) right now, which has more than one and a half hour). But GMail says it just "Couldn't sync", so I cannot see nor send any new emails.

If there's an emergency and I need to communicate by email, I just cannot, because Google has no option besides "sync" the GMail app. It could obviously show new emails as plain text, without saving anything to disk.

Is there any reasoning behind this absurd (emails are much smaller than a 1:35h video), or is it just another *planned obsolescence* behavior?

Comment: I think it's planned. Sync kills itself off at low storage to stop a system halt from lack of memory (needs space, man) while YouTube caches, wipes the cache for each video, and also only stores one or two minutes to rewind to save space.

Comment: Why not empty the cache for emails? I'm only interested in the last emails I received. If I wanna dig further, I can search just like I do with videos on YouTube, or I can just browse the list, as with any YouTube list.

Comment: You could clear cache fully and try that?

Comment: @DanBrown At Gmail General settings I've found "Clear search history" and "Clear picture approvals". In Data usage, I've found "Sync Gmail", which I disabled (hoping it was "the cure"). Even after disabling it, closing all apps and opening it again, turning the phone off and on, I still got the message "Couldn't sync" when trying to update the inbox. How do I "clear cache fully", as you say? Do you mean Gmail cache? Or Android's?

Comment: Android's. It might also be worth clearing gmails app data too.